# Удаление html-тега обертки с помощью js или jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Нужно удалить теги, в которые вложены другие теги, но чтобы эти вложенные теги остались. Например,

```html
<div>
 <div>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
  <p>lorem ipsum</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Здесь удалить все `<div>`, чтобы остались только `<p>` с текстом.

Answer (score 1):

При повторном добавлении элемента в дом-модель он удаляется из старого местоположения, таким образом достаточно добавить `p` в новый контейнер а потом удалить все `div`

---

Вот так без жуквери:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach(p => document.body.append(p));
document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => div.remove());
```

```html
<div><div><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p></div></div>
```

---

Вот так с:

```js
$('body').append($('p'));
$('div').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><div><p>lorem ipsum</p><p>lorem ipsum</p></div></div>
```